# json to C# object how to deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json

How to deserialize this json string in C#

> {
>       "accountant": {
>           "sysid": "1",
>           "first_name": "Test",
>           "last_name": "Test",
>           "product_type": "Sample"
>       }
>   }

What I tried so far is using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

`var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountantData>(responseMessage);`

this is my Model

```
public class AccountantData
{
    [JsonProperty("accountant")]
    public List<UserData> Accountant { get; set; }
}
public class UserData
{
    public UserData(int sysId, string firstName, string lastName, string productType)
    {
        SystemId = sysId;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ProductType = productType;
    }

    [JsonProperty("sysid")]
    public int SystemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_type")]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

but this results to an error

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.UserData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON input  string is not correct. `AccountantData` uses `List` (Array) of `UserData`. Try this:

```
{
   "accountant":[
      {
         "sysid":"1",
         "first_name":"Test",
         "last_name":"Test",
         "product_type":"Sample"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Update:**
If you are always going to have a single object of `UserData` then you can change your `AccountantData` class as:

```
public class AccountantData
{
  [JsonProperty("accountant")]
  UserData Accountant { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in case you will always have single `UserData` object and you have control of JSON data, then you can update your JSON input data to simpler format as below:

```
{
   "sysid":"1",
   "first_name":"Test",
   "last_name":"Test",
   "product_type":"Sample"
}
```

and then deserialize it like this:

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(responseMessage);
```

Comment: i use json_encode after getting the rowdata. do i need to format it to become array when i json_encode?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with json_encode if I understood your question correctly. If your JSON data is always going to have a single UserData object then you can update your AccountantData class. I have updated my answer with explaination.